# Caliburn.Micro and DataGrid: Reliable approach for detecting individual cell changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, caliburn.micro

I have an MVVM-based WPF application that relies on *Caliburn.Micro*.

In one view, I am displaying a `DataGrid` and a `Button`. The `DataGrid` displays a collection of items, where the item class derives from `PropertyChangedBase`.
The button should be enabled or disabled based on the contents in the editable `DataGrid` cells. What is the most reliable approach to achieve this with *Caliburn.Micro*?

Schematically, this is what my code looks right now:

```
public class ItemViewModel : PropertyChangedBase { }

...

public class ItemsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private IObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _items;

    // This is the DataGrid in ItemsView
    public IObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }

    // This is the button in ItemsView
    public void DoWork() { }

    // This is the button enable "switch" in ItemsView
    public bool CanDoWork
    {
        get { return Items.All(item => item.NotifiableProperty == some_state); }
    }
}
```

As the code stands, there is *no* notification to `ItemsViewModel.CanDoWork` when one `NotifiableProperty` is changed, for example when the user edits one cell in the `ItemsView`´s `DataGrid`. Hence, the `DoWork` button enable state will never be changed.

One possible workaround is to add an (anonymous) event handler to every item in the `Items` collection:

```
foreach (var item in Items)
    item.PropertyChanged += 
        (sender, args) => NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanDoWork);
```

but then I also need to keep track of when (if) items are added or removed from the `Items` collection, or if the `Items` collection is re-initialized altogether.

Is there a more elegant and reliable solution to this problem? I am sure there is, but so far I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a case where INPC works well; to simplify registering/deregistering adds and deletes just add a CollectionChanged  handler to your Items collection:

```
Items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsCollectionChanged;

private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0) {
        foreach (ItemViewModel  vm in e.NewItems)
            vm.PropertyChanged += OnDetailVmChanged;
    }
    if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0) {
        foreach (ItemViewModel  vm in e.OldItems) {
            vm.PropertyChanged -= OnDetailVmChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Josh Smith wrote a PropertyObserver class [here](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/) that I find more elegant than shotgun INPC tracking, but in a master-detail scenario like yours you would still have to track the adds and deletes.

**EDIT by Anders Gustafsson**
Note that for the above code to work in the general case requires that `Items` has been initialized with the default constructor before the event handler is attached. To ensure that `OnDetailVmChanged` event handlers are correctly added and removed, the `Items` property setter need to be extended to something like this:

```
public IObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        // If required, initialize empty _items collection and attach
        // event handler
        if (_items == null) {
            _items = new BindableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
            _items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsCollectionChanged;
        }
        // Clear old contents in _items
        _items.Clear();
        // Add value item:s one by one to _items
        if (value != null) foreach (var item in value) _items.Add(item);

        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
    }
}
```

(And of course, with the above `Items` setter in place, the topmost `Items.CollectionChanged` event handler attachment should not be included in the code.)

Ideally, I would have used `if (value != null) _items.AddRange(value);`, but when the `AddRange` method triggers the `OnItemsCollectionChanged` event handler, `e.NewItems` appear to be empty (or `null`). I have not explicitly verified that `e.OldItems` is non-null when the `Clear()` method is invoked; otherwise `Clear()` would also need to be replaced with one-by-one removal of the item:s in `_items`.

Comment: Thanks, good point! I will try it out as soon as possible and report back.

Comment: I have now tried to apply your solution above and in principle it works, although there are some problems with the code. First, `e.NewItems` and `e.OldItems` contain `object`:s, so some kind of casting is required before attaching the `OnDetailVmChanged` event handler. (I took the approach `foreach var vm in e.NewItems.OfType<ItemViewModel>())`, but there are alternatives of course). Second, out-of-the-box the approach above only works *after* `Items` is initialized with an *empty* collection, and it will be invalidated as soon as you re-initialize `Items`. ...

Comment: @AndersGustafsson. Yeah, this is a case where var is not your friend, which is why I strongly type the variable. You *could* just linq-out and add a Cast<> after OfType<>(), but it looks noisy to me. Why not edit your original post with the code you wound up with though? It's hard to really understand code in these comments. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, my mistake about the casting, I had actually missed that strong typing of `vm` would work in this case. Regarding the code in the comment, I included it there in case you wanted to update the answer with your own "touch", but I'll add the code in your answer to make it more complete. Edit afterwards as you wish. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever a property changes fire RaiseCanExecuteChanged for the button cummand command?

For Example :

```
public DelegateCommand<object> MyDeleteCommand { get; set; }

string _mySelectedItem;
    public string MySelectedItem
    {
        get { return _mySelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _mySelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
            MyDeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @SarafTalukder. However, the above does not specifically apply to _Caliburn.Micro_, right? And it also provides no guidance on efficiently attaching/detaching event handlers for the added/removed items of my collection, right? I am not being ungrateful, but I'll downvote the answer at this stage since I cannot see that you are trying to answer my question. I will be more than happy to upvote it again if you can explicitly address my question, or explain more thoroughly whether I have misunderstood something in your answer.